# In SQL, how to substring between 2 special characters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on SQL Server 2012, I would like to take a substring between the 2nd and 3rd comma in the below string.

Input:

```
IP-TEXT

1CAT, 2DOG, 5.5, AAA, BE TTY
TR2, 5lo, 9.1, LOL, ROFL
PP09, 4432, 6, USA, UK
```

Required output:

```
OP-TEXT

5.5
9.1
6
```

Can anyone please help with a SQL query?

Comment: Can yuo also add `XYZ, ",", ',', QQQ, TTT` to the input, and adjust the expected output?

Comment: yes, those type of inputs are also present in some records.

Comment: e.g. one of the records is like <br> XX,”flames,pl”,55,ABC,PQR

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`CHARINDEX`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(IP_TEXT, t2.p+1, t3.p - t2.p - 1) AS OP_TEXT
FROM mytable 
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', IP_TEXT)) AS t1(p)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', IP_TEXT, t1.p+1)) AS t2(p)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX(',', IP_TEXT, t2.p+1)) AS t3(p)
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgos Betsos!

Comment: @juned Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this,or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

CROSS APPLY function works.
I also found another method to fetch the value between 2,d and 3rd comma. Below is the query -

```
substring(IP-TEXT, 
          CHARINDEX(',',IP-TEXT,
          (CHARINDEX(',', IP-TEXT) + 1)) + 1, 
           CHARINDEX(',',IP-TEXT,
          (CHARINDEX(',',IP-TEXT,
          (CHARINDEX(',',IP-TEXT)+1))+1))-    
           CHARINDEX(',',IP-TEXT,
          (CHARINDEX(',',IP-TEXT)+1)))
```

Appreciate your help folks :)